# Tic Tac Toe button colors

Tags: java, swing, tic-tac-toe

I have been updating a somewhat outdated tic tac toe code I found online (Like it actually works now :P) I have it nearly complete but I keep having one same problem. The 3x3 buttons inside the tic tac toe board work perfectly,except for one thing, the color after they are clicked is always the background, I have made attempts to correct this but all it does is make the buttons not change color at all. The two colors are red and green and I would like it so that when each player clicks a button it changes to their color.

The main game code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToeGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
JLabel l1;
JLabel p1namel;
JLabel p2namel;
JLabel l3;
JButton b1;
JButton b2;
JButton b3;
JButton b4;
JButton b5;
JButton b6;
JButton b7;
JButton b8;
JButton b9;
int  b1ctr = 1 ,b2ctr = 2 ,b3ctr = 3 ,b4ctr = 4, b5ctr = 5, b6ctr = 6, b7ctr = 7, b8ctr = 8, b9ctr = 9; 
Font textfont = new Font( "Serif", Font.PLAIN,70 );
int ctr = 1;
String p1name,p2name;

public TicTacToeGame(String p1,String p2) 
{
    TicTacToeGameLayout customLayout = new TicTacToeGameLayout();

    getContentPane().setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    getContentPane().setLayout(customLayout);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    l1 = new JLabel("");
    getContentPane().add(l1);

    p1name = p1;
    p2name = p2; 

    p1namel = new JLabel("");
    p1namel.setText(p1);
    p1namel.setFont(textfont);
    p1namel.setForeground(Color.RED);
    getContentPane().add(p1namel);

    p2namel = new JLabel("");
    p2namel.setText(p2);
    p2namel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
     p2namel.setFont(textfont);
    getContentPane().add(p2namel);

    l3 = new JLabel("<->");
     l3.setFont(textfont);
    getContentPane().add(l3);

    b1 = new JButton("");
    getContentPane().add(b1);

    b2 = new JButton("");
    getContentPane().add(b2);

    b3 = new JButton("");
    getContentPane().add(b3);

    b4 = new JButton("");
    getContentPane().add(b4);

    b5 = new JButton("");
    getContentPane().add(b5);

    b6 = new JButton("");
    getContentPane().add(b6);

    b7 = new JButton("");
    getContentPane().add(b7);

    b8 = new JButton("");
    getContentPane().add(b8);

    b9 = new JButton("");
    getContentPane().add(b9);


    l3.setForeground(Color.WHITE); 

     b1.setFont(textfont);
     b2.setFont(textfont);
     b3.setFont(textfont);
     b4.setFont(textfont);
     b5.setFont(textfont);
     b6.setFont(textfont);
     b7.setFont(textfont);
     b8.setFont(textfont);
     b9.setFont(textfont);

     b1.addActionListener(this);
     b2.addActionListener(this);
     b3.addActionListener(this);
     b4.addActionListener(this);
     b5.addActionListener(this);
     b6.addActionListener(this);
     b7.addActionListener(this);
     b8.addActionListener(this);
     b9.addActionListener(this);

    setSize(getPreferredSize());

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)

    {

     if (ctr % 2 == 1)

        {

         if(ae.getSource() == b1)   
            {


                b1ctr = 0;
                b1.setEnabled(false);
                b1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                winnerfind();
                ctr++;      

            }
            else if (ae.getSource() == b2)

                {

                b2ctr = 0;
                b2.setEnabled(false);
                b2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);  
                winnerfind();
                ctr++;

                }
                else if (ae.getSource() == b3)

                {

                b3ctr = 0;
                b3.setEnabled(false);
                b3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);  
                winnerfind();
                ctr++;

                }
                else if (ae.getSource() == b4)

                {

                b4ctr = 0;
                b4.setEnabled(false);
                b4.setBackground(Color.GREEN);  
                winnerfind();
                ctr++;

                }
                else if (ae.getSource() == b5)

                {

                b5ctr = 0;
                b5.setEnabled(false);
                b5.setBackground(Color.GREEN);  
                winnerfind();
                ctr++;

                }
                else if (ae.getSource() == b6)

                {

                b6ctr = 0;
                b6.setEnabled(false);
                b6.setBackground(Color.GREEN);  
                winnerfind();
                ctr++;

                }
                else if (ae.getSource() == b7)

                {

                b7ctr = 0;
                b7.setEnabled(false);
                b7.setBackground(Color.GREEN);  
                winnerfind();
                ctr++;

                }
                else if (ae.getSource() == b8)

                {

                b8ctr = 0;
                b8.setEnabled(false);
                b8.setBackground(Color.GREEN);  
                winnerfind();
                ctr++;

                }
                else if (ae.getSource() == b9)

                {

                b9ctr = 0;
                b9.setEnabled(false);
                b9.setBackground(Color.GREEN);  
                winnerfind();
                ctr++;

                }

        }
        else if (ctr % 2 != 1)

                {

                if(ae.getSource() == b1)    
                    {


                        b1ctr = 1;
                        b1.setEnabled(false);
                        b1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        winnerfind1();
                        ctr++;      

                    }
                    else if (ae.getSource() == b2)

                        {

                        b2ctr = 1;  
                        b2.setEnabled(false);
                        b2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        winnerfind1();
                        ctr++;

                        }
                        else if (ae.getSource() == b3)

                        {

                        b3ctr = 1;
                        b3.setEnabled(false);
                        b3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 
                        winnerfind1();
                        ctr++;

                        }
                        else if (ae.getSource() == b4)

                        {

                        b4ctr = 1;
                        b4.setEnabled(false);   
                        b4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        winnerfind1();
                        ctr++;

                        }
                        else if (ae.getSource() == b5)

                        {

                        b5ctr = 1;
                        b5.setEnabled(false);   
                        b5.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        winnerfind1();
                        ctr++;

                        }
                        else if (ae.getSource() == b6)

                        {

                        b6ctr = 1;
                        b6.setEnabled(false);   
                        b6.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        winnerfind1();
                        ctr++;

                        }
                        else if (ae.getSource() == b7)

                        {

                        b7ctr = 1;
                        b7.setEnabled(false);   
                        b7.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        winnerfind1();
                        ctr++;

                        }
                        else if (ae.getSource() == b8)

                        {

                        b8ctr = 1;
                        b8.setEnabled(false);   
                        b8.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        winnerfind1();
                        ctr++;

                        }
                        else if (ae.getSource() == b9)

                        {

                        b9ctr = 1;
                        b9.setEnabled(false);   
                        b9.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        winnerfind1();
                        ctr++;

                        }




            }



    }

    public void winnerfind()

        {

        if ((b1ctr == 0 && b2ctr == 0 && b3ctr == 0) || (b1ctr == 0 && b4ctr == 0 && b7ctr == 0) || (b2ctr == 0 && b5ctr == 0 && b8ctr == 0) || (b3ctr == 0 && b6ctr == 0 && b9ctr == 0) || (b4ctr == 0 && b5ctr == 0 && b6ctr == 0) || (b7ctr == 0 && b8ctr == 0 && b9ctr == 0) || (b1ctr == 0 && b5ctr == 0 && b9ctr == 0) || (b3ctr == 0 && b5ctr == 0 && b7ctr == 0))

            {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+p1name+" is the winner!");

            }   



        }


    public void winnerfind1()

        {

        if ((b1ctr == 1 && b2ctr == 1 && b3ctr == 1) || (b1ctr == 1 && b4ctr == 1 && b7ctr == 1) || (b2ctr == 1 && b5ctr == 1 && b8ctr == 1) || (b3ctr == 1 && b6ctr == 1 && b9ctr == 1) || (b4ctr == 1 && b5ctr == 1 && b6ctr == 1) || (b7ctr == 1 && b8ctr == 1 && b9ctr == 1) || (b1ctr == 1 && b5ctr == 1 && b9ctr == 1) || (b3ctr == 1 && b5ctr == 1 && b7ctr == 1))

            {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+p2name+" is victorious!");    

            }   



        }


}

class TicTacToeGameLayout implements LayoutManager 
{

public TicTacToeGameLayout() 
{
}

public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) 
{
}

public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) 
{
}

public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) 
{
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);

    Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
    dim.width = 719 + insets.left + insets.right;
    dim.height = 455 + insets.top + insets.bottom;

    return dim;
}

public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) 
{
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
    return dim;
}

public void layoutContainer(Container parent) 
{
    Insets insets = parent.getInsets();

    Component c;
    c = parent.getComponent(0);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+0,insets.top+64,720,8);}
    c = parent.getComponent(1);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+16,insets.top+8,428,80);}
    c = parent.getComponent(2);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+472,insets.top+8,528,80);}
    c = parent.getComponent(3);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+300,insets.top+8,150,80);}
    c = parent.getComponent(4);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+176,insets.top+112,120,104);}
    c = parent.getComponent(5);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+296,insets.top+112,112,104);}
    c = parent.getComponent(6);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+408,insets.top+112,120,104);}
    c = parent.getComponent(7);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+176,insets.top+216,120,96);}
    c = parent.getComponent(8);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+296,insets.top+216,112,96);}
    c = parent.getComponent(9);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+408,insets.top+216,120,96);}
    c = parent.getComponent(10);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+176,insets.top+312,120,104);}
    c = parent.getComponent(11);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+296,insets.top+312,112,104);}
    c = parent.getComponent(12);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+408,insets.top+312,120,104);}
   }
}
```

Comment: This is off-topic, but you may want to try refactoring that huge `if` chain into a new method so that you can cut down on copy-paste code.

Comment: Bob, there are no stupid questions here (well, there are, but this isn't one of them). I applaud your attempt to learn programming. Let's see if we can help you out.

Comment: I know, I most definitely will once I get this functioning. That is a battle for another day when I have more energy, as I said I am a bit of a beginner so it takes me a tad longer xD. (Directed at the first comment)

Comment: @bob138 Can you clarify what is your desired output?

Comment: Say player red clicked a button, that button would then become red. This is just so its a little easier to follow the gameplay, when its all the same color it gets pretty confusing.

Comment: To clarify, it is what I see now: when player *red* click a button it become *green*, and when player *green* click a button it become *yellow*. Is the color the problem? If it is, there are a bunch of statement like `b1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);`, and you need to change it to the correct color.

Comment: Wow. My amazement that there is a tic-tac-toe tag at _all_ is exceeded only by my amazement that it has actually gathered some followers :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing really wrong with that code, other than the fact that you're using yellow instead of red - if you want to change that, just change all occurrences of `Color.YELLOW` to `Color.RED`, and swap the colors for the two players for consistency:

```
p1namel = new JLabel("");
p1namel.setText(p1);
p1namel.setFont(textfont);
p1namel.setForeground(Color.GREEN); // << HERE
getContentPane().add(p1namel);

p2namel = new JLabel("");
p2namel.setText(p2);
p2namel.setForeground(Color.RED); // << AND HERE
p2namel.setFont(textfont);
getContentPane().add(p2namel);
```

When I add some support code to the bottom of it to get the frame running:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TicTacToeGame frame = new TicTacToeGame("pax","diablo");
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

it appears to work fine (other than mismatched colors):

[image]

By making the changes as shown above, you end up with:

[image]

Comment: This is what I see: player red -> button green; player green -> button yellow. (Not simply using yellow instead of red.)

Comment: @johnchen902, see the update: easiest solution is to change all YELLOW to RED and swap player name colors as shown.

Comment: Why don't you keep the buttons' color and just change the players' color to YELLOW and GREEN? :)

Comment: Me using the yellow was just that I had the old colors as green and yellow but decided to change it just before publishing the question (Code was out of date, but I've updated it now). But when I run it as is, it has all of the buttons colored when clicked.

Comment: @johnchen902, that's another solution certainly but I got the impression from the question that OP wanted red and green. If they don't care then it's easier just to change the player colors (and ensure you output the right winner of course - I haven't checked that).